# Microcontroller is being restarted on function return

Tags: c, 8051, keil

I have 8051 MCU and I use keil to program it with C. But in some functions when the function ends and it gets to the return line the MCU is restated. For example a piece of my code is

```
 while(!ctsWentHigh)
    {
        radio_comm_PollCTS();
    }
```

while returning  radio_comm_PollCTS()  the MCU is restarted. If I change the code to

```
 while(!ctsWentHigh)
    {
        cstvals = radio_comm_PollCTS();
    }
```

it works and the MCU is not restarted. But this solution does not work in all cases and some other functions return and reset the MCU. (not all of them)

I have a doubt that the problem might be for the tool chain integration

Linker settings

CODE REMOVEUNUSED CLASSES(BIT(0x20.0-0x2F.7), DATA(D:0-D:0x7F), IDATA(I:0-I:0xFF), XDATA(X:0-X:0xFFF), CODE(C:0-C:0xFBFF), CONST(C:0-C:0xFBFF))

compiler settings

DB OE BR Small OPTIMIZE(11, SIZE) DEFINE(SILABS_PLATFORM_WMB912) DEFINE(SILABS_WMCU_SI106x)

Assembler settings

XR GEN DB EP NOMOD51

Kindly help if you know the answer I am in urgent situation.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a **stack overflow** to me. We would need to see all of your code to verify this. Some 8051 variants support debugging - you could check the stack pointer and memory on these.

Comment: I uploaded my project here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AivB_SrRBF80a2XX4V8AX1wqOyE
I have a debugger but i dont see any stack section.

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory access violation in your radio_comm_PollCTS() function.

Comment: Most likely cause of that type of behavior is an out-of-bounds access to a local variable.

Comment: Try using LARGE memory model. The small model puts everything in `data`, which also contains the stack.

Comment: Not worked, still having this issue @TurboJ