# Program counter goes to the end of code and 8051 Restarts

Tags: c, 8051, keil

I have an 8051 MCU which I use keil to program it with C. My problem is that the micro-controller restarts at the end of some functions while they should return.

Using a debugger I tried to check it line by line. And I figured out the the MCU is not restated right after the end of the function. The PC(progam counter) goes to somewhere else (sometime somewhere that there is not any code to execute) and then it increases one by one until the end of code. It is very strange for me because I write my code in C and never seen the type of error previously.

I think this problem might be related to the compiler settings and thus I post the settings here:

Assembler settings:
XR GEN DB EP NOMOD51

Compiler settings: 
DB OE BR LARGE OPTIMIZE(11, SIZE) DEFINE(SILABS_PLATFORM_WMB912) DEFINE(SILABS_WMCU_SI106x)

Linker settings:
CODE REMOVEUNUSED CLASSES(BIT(0x20.0-0x2F.7), DATA(D:0-D:0x7F), IDATA(I:0-I:0xFF), XDATA(X:0-X:0xFFF), CODE(C:0-C:0xFBFF), CONST(C:0-C:0xFBFF))

I tried both large and small settings but the problem remains.
Kindly help me if you know the reason.

Comment: Can you post the exact MCU model you're using? That would be helpful as well as the code you're trying to run.

Comment: Seeing the code would help people answer. It could be that it's overwriting the memory locations needed for the return.

Comment: Does it crash if you go *into* the function or when you return? The latter most likely cause is an out-of-bounds write to a local array.

Comment: Seems to be the same story you told earlier: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/363239/microcontroller-is-being-restarted-on-function-return . Is this a different question?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AivB_SrRBF80bPzWuZuWEj7f9g8 My project can be found. The mcu model is SI1064. Yes I wrote another question because I made some new improvements and wanted to ask with this conditions. @georgjz

Comment: It crashes while returning.

Comment: what is the 'mode' that the microprocessor is being booted into?   the stack is quite small,  so the code could be overrunning the stack space.

Comment: What do you mean by 'mode'?

Comment: 'mode'  there are some (2 or 3, I forget the exact details) GPIO pins that determine the boot mode of the microprocessor.

Comment: which function return fails?  The same one every time or does it vary?

Comment: what is the complete stack back trace to the function that fails?

Comment: is any of your code enabling the watchdog timer?  if so, then where/what is the code that initializes the watchdog timer?  Where/what is the code that resets the watchdog timer? Does your code have a interrupt vector table and functions for each of the possible interrupts?

Comment: The program crashes at the following path 
vInitializeHW() (main.c) -> vRadioInit() (radio.c) -> si4455_get_int_status() (si4455_api_lib.c)
I can place breakpoints at the end of the following function and track it. If i place another breakpoint after it, the program can not reach it. If check it line by line after reaching the function return, the PC goes to somewhere wrong and sometimes somewhere that no code is programed and sometimes to another part of the code which it should not go. I do not enable the WDT any where in the code and I disable the interrupts but the problem remains.

Comment: @user3629249 please help if you know the reason

Comment: @BobJacobsen I posted the code in comments

Comment: do you have the source code for that library?  (working from memory here) can you setup the 8051 so it uses the page of ram rather than the tiny (default) area for the stack?

Comment: Yes, I placed it here in about ten previous comments before here. I want to modify a source code for doing some tasks and I found the problems. I have also doubt about using SEGMENT_VARIABLE in the code which may cause stack to corrupt.

Comment: I can change the memory model from small to large and it would place most of the data in the large exram. and there is just 11 bytes occupied in internall ram but the problem still remains but with different functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the reason. It is actually the problem of the compiler. The keil C51 v9.53 has a problem that sometimes it mixes the stack with data. They have proposed a new linker. But I upgraded to v 9.55 and the problem solved.

Comment: You can mark this as the accepted answer to indicate the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You’re probably overwriting the stack, thereby corrupting the return address.

It would be good to see the actual code, not just a sketch. But one possible cause is passing an argument of the wrong size or type, so that the routine you’re calling thinks it’s writing to somewhere safe but is actually writing outside what you provided with the call.

It’s possible that there’s not enough stack space, too.  Particularly if you’re calling a complicated function that calls other things.

But without real detail, it’s hard to say more.

Comment: Thank u. I posted a link in previous comments which contains my full project.